# How do I return records which are never equal to 1 when the same record is present several times in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  |  Is_Final   |    SEQ    |  State
-------------------------------------------
A1       0             12        Pending
A1       0             13        Quoted
B1       0             14        Pending 
B1       1             15        Quoted
C1       0             11        Pending 
C1       0             12        Pending
C1       0             13        Quoted


SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE IS_FINAL = 1)
```

I have given my query above but what I am trying to do is, return all distinct IDs and their State where the IS_FINAL was never equal to 1 in all instances of the ID in the table and the max Seq number.

So based on the sameple I'd like to return:

```
ID    |   State
A1        Quoted
C1        Quoted
```

Comment: Why not just do 'select distinct ID, State from table where IS_Final != 1'? I don't think you have any real reasont to be hitting that table a second time.

Comment: Since you've already figured out how to get the IDs that don't have a 1, is it fair to say your only question is how to get the last row for each of those?

Comment: The marked dupe is incorrect.  But the simple solution isn't the solution here.  Re-read the question and note that B1 isn't desired in the returned recordset.

Comment: @TabAlleman: The way the OP has started they indeed only need to apply any of the known greatest-n-per-group techniques. But it's also possible to solve this in a way where you do both the row group exclusion part and the greatest-n-per-group part kind of simultaneously. (Maybe there are appropriate duplicate targets for that too, I'm not sure.) Anyway, I've re-opened the question so far to invite a wider range of solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I've come up with a pretty simple solution that works for you and should be pretty easy to follow. Answer and demo is up top explaination to follow.

```
create table #SOQ (
    ID char(2),
    Is_Final smallint,
    SEQ int,
    State varchar(30))

insert into #SOQ values ('A1', 0 , 12, 'Pending') 
insert into #SOQ values ('A1', 0 , 13, 'Quoted') 
insert into #SOQ values ('B1', 0 , 14, 'Pending') 
insert into #SOQ values ('B1', 1 , 15, 'Quoted') 
insert into #SOQ values ('C1', 0 , 11, 'Pending') 
insert into #SOQ values ('C1', 0 , 12, 'Pending') 
insert into #SOQ values ('C1', 0 , 13, 'Quoted') 

select distinct
    A.ID,
    State
from #SOQ as A
inner join (
    select 
        ID,
        Max(SEQ) as MaxSEQ
    from #SOQ
    where ID not in (
        select
            ID
        from #SOQ
        where Is_Final =1)
    group by ID) as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
    and A.SEQ = B.MaxSEQ
```

So in the internal portion of this query we are grabbing the `max` sequence numbers since you want the latest values.

```
select 
    ID,
    Max(SEQ) as MaxSEQ
from #SOQ
```

Then we need to eliminate any values that have the is final. We can do that with some form of anti join. For simplicity's sake I've chosen `NOT IN` however `NOT EXISTS` would also work an may even perform better.

```
select 
    ID,
    Max(SEQ) as MaxSEQ
from #SOQ
where ID not in (
    select
        ID
    from #SOQ
    where Is_Final =1)
```

Then at the top we are taking your distinct ID and State values and joining to that subquery to give the final resulsts.

```
select distinct
    A.ID,
    State
from #SOQ as A
inner join (
    select 
        ID,
        Max(SEQ) as MaxSEQ
    from #SOQ
    where ID not in (
        select
            ID
        from #SOQ
        where Is_Final =1)
    group by ID) as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
    and A.SEQ = B.MaxSEQ
```

Which results in.

```
ID  State
A1  Quoted
C1  Quoted
```

I hope that explaination helps you get to where you need to go.

Edit: I've added an example of using `not exists` to accomplish this as well.

```
select distinct
    A.ID,
    State
from #SOQ as A
inner join (
    select 
        ID,
        Max(SEQ) as MaxSEQ
    from #SOQ as NE
    where not exists (
        select
            1
        from #SOQ 
        where Is_Final =1
            and NE.ID = ID )
    group by ID) as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
    and A.SEQ = B.MaxSEQ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` with `row_number()` :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.IS_FINAL = 1)
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by seq desc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query.

```
create table #temp (ID varchar(5), Is_Final int, SEQ int, States Varchar(20))

insert into #temp values ('A1', 0, 12, 'Pending'),
('A1', 0, 13, 'Quoted'),
('B1', 0, 14, 'Pending'), 
('B1', 1, 15, 'Quoted'), 
('C1', 0, 11, 'Pending'),
('C1', 0, 12, 'Pending'),
('C1', 0, 13, 'Quoted')

select * into #NewTable from
(
select ID, MAX(seq) as MaxSeq FROM #temp group by id
)a
-- delete from #NewTable where ID in (select distinct ID FROM #temp where Is_Final = 1)

select #temp.ID, States from #NewTable
inner join #temp on #NewTable.ID = #temp.ID and #temp.SEQ = 
#NewTable.MaxSeq
where #temp.ID not in (select distinct ID FROM #temp where Is_Final = 1)

drop table #NewTable
drop table #temp
```

The output is as follows

```
ID  States
A1  Quoted
C1  Quoted
```

Here in new table all id and max sequence has been selected and inserted. After this all id which is_final is 1 has been deleted.
Finally for result join has been used based on Id and Max sequence.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work:

```
SELECT ID,FstValue FROM
(
SELECT 
    ID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID,SEQ DESC) RankOrder
    ,FIRST_VALUE(State) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) FstValue
FROM
    Table
WHERE 
    ID NOT IN (select DISTINCT ID from Table where Is_Final = 1)
    )m
WHERE RankOrder = 1
```

I have used `DENSE_RANK()` and `FIRST_VALUE` functions to do this.

Initially, since you don't have Unique PK value, listed, generate that for each `ID` and `SEQ` combination. Then get the `FIRST_VALUE` for each combination in DESCENDING order(this is important), which will help us get the latest row first and then filter it for the first row.